# Where is the WebMatrix main config file?

Tags: webmatrix

I want to tweak the main config file for web matrix. I thought I found it in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft WebMatrix\config\applicationHost.config
```

but changing the file and restarting WebMatrix has no effect. Where can I find the file that it's using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worked it out. The config file WebMatrix actually uses is in IISExpress8\config in your My Documents folder, called applicationHost.config

Comment: Mine was located at "[My Documents]\IISExpress\Config\ApplicationHost.config" -- never would have guess it was under my documents.  It's pretty baffling that MS would put a configuration file in such a place (and also have faux ones elsewhere).

Answer (score 1):

For WebMatrix beta release config file was in %userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress8\config, but now (WebMatrix released), path is %userprofile%\my documents\iisexpress\config